# Disable form window resize?

Tags: html, forms, resize, window

Here is my form:

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="php/html_form_send.php" onsubmit="window.open('','my_form_target', 'width=500,height=260', true); this.target='my_form_target';" >
```

Now is their anyway on the window open I can disable the window from being re sized like `resize=no` or `resize=none` or something like that? Also if there is where would I place it?

Comment: It would be terrifying if a web page had that much control

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no syntax for allowing you to disable resizing, and if there were, most browsers (I hope) would ignore it

EDIT:
other answers have pointed out that the syntax does indeed exist for the window.open() method. However it does not appear to work in any browser I have tested

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open ("page_url","windowName","resizable=0");
```